# Is it normal to apply for a PhD when you have not done your master's thesis in that subject?

Tags: phd, masters, application

I have recently finished my master's thesis and I want to start applying for PhDs soon. Considering that I did my PhD in subject A would it be considered 'normal' to apply for PhDs in subject B? I feel that *not* doing your master's thesis in subject B would set you back in the sense that you would miss out on quite a bit of hands on experience in that subject. How much are you expected to learn while doing the PhD and how much is expected as prerequisite knowledge?

I did my master's in Theoretical Physics if that's relevant and subject A = simulations in soft condensed matter and subject B = quantum computing (but maybe other subjects still)

Comment: In my experience it is very common.

Comment: Both of those are physics, and really not that unrelated. Now if you now wanted to do a PhD in Roman History, that might (but only might) make some difference.

Comment: That's what i did and I got admitted to a Ph.D. program in the US, but it was 15 yrs ago.